# HP G60 WiFi driver defaults to A/G/N with no B network

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have an HP G60 243CL Laptop. When it was bought the WIFI driver was set to 802.11 a/g/n only with no b network support. Since I have b network in my house I called support  and they helped me update the driver. Now, few month later, the driver somehow went back to the A/G/N default and I can't connect to my home network.
The laptop has an Atheros wireless card.

Where can I get the right driver and any special steps to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-70744-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=2093&product=3860190

This is the official driver for windows vista for that wireless card.

As for changing the wireless card mode, do you use the windows built in wireless software or does that laptop use its own special hp wireless connectivity software?

Ok so you have the windows built in wireless software.

Go to Start Menu->Control Panel->Change to "Classic View"->Device Manager-> Go to the the network adapters-> double click your wireless card-->Advanced Tab->"Property" Select "Wireless Mode"--> change "Value" to the "IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n" mode

Comment: I have this driver already. Doesn't do the trick. I'm missing some steps. I'm using the default Vista wireless software

Comment: Just added what I think you need. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I see no "Wireless Mode" in the properties list. Or anything similar with the a/b/g/n values available :(

Comment: What options do you see in the property list?